# skip duplicate file using java

Tags: java

Can anyone help me to skip file having extension "read" in my code ?

I have two files in my folder:

- 123.csv
- 123.csv.read

After execution every csv file is converted into ".csv.read", but if the same file comes again, that file should be skipped.

Like this file (123.csv.read) has been processed already, so if same new file(123.csv) comes, I want to be skipped that file.

In my code below, after 123.csv file is processed, the folder has only one file `123.csv.read`. `break` is not behaving as I was expecting.

```
context.Str = ((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILEPATH"));

String extension = context.Str.substring(context.Str.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);

if (extension.equals("read"))
{
    break;
}
else {
    System.out.println("Good File to Process");
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post and format your code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl+K

Comment: "Break is not behaving I was expecting."  What did you expect it to do this case?

Comment: I think that will break that loop and will not allow that file further as well. Am I right ?

Comment: If you use break to stop a loop, you should include that loop. However, only include relevant parts. See how to write a [mcve]

Comment: Sorry to use wrong words, its if else condition(I'm new). I take my words back, What could be done in this if else condition to break and not forward duplicate file ?

Comment: In an if-then-else construct there is no point in trying to break, since you're already executing only a certain part of your code, based on how the conditions evaluate.  In your example, you will print "Good File to Process" if, and only if `extension.equals("read")` evaluates to `false`.

Comment: @azurefrog, May I know how to evaluate extension.equals("read") condition false ?

Comment: You would know this because it would branch to the else Part thus printing your "good File...". Do you physicly rename the File? This would fail if they are in the same directory because the file already exist.

Comment: @reineckm,  
csv files are coming from source and storing into FOLDER. Its a ETL process. So after receiving files to folder etl process those files and after processing convert that file into file.csv.read My concern is if any file come which already has been process and converted to file.csv.read extension, should not be iterated further and converted into file.csv.alreadyprocessed Hope now you got the idea what a trying to say ?

Comment: Let me rephrase: 1. For every file named *.csv -> do something; rename to *.csv.read  2. For every File named *.csv.read -> do something different; rename to *.csv.alreadyprocessed. OK? So what your code as of now does is: set context.Str to something. Set extension to whatever comes after the last "." or the whole filename if no "." appears. Then it prints "Good File to Process" if extension equals "read". So your problem is not in the code provided. Add a System.out.println(extension); before the if and replace break; with System.out.println("! " + extension); to better understand yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

For example 123.csv file came again, then you check this if exist in read folder

```
if(!new File(123.csv+".read").exist()) { 
      // if this file is not exist, then it means that this has not been processed
      // process the file
} else {
      // do some other staff
}
```

**Edit:** Or you can try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File dir = new File("your_path");
        File[] processedFiles = dir.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File pathname) {
                return pathname.getName().contains("read");
            }
        });
        List<File> files = Arrays.asList(processedFiles);
        File[] noneProcessedFiles = dir.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File pathname) {
                return !pathname.getName().contains("read");
            }
        });

        for (File file : noneProcessedFiles) {
            if (!files.stream().findAny().get().getName().contains(file.getName())) {
                // process the file....
                System.out.println("Not found ... " + file.getName());
            } else {
                // do some other staff....
                System.out.println("Fount the file");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: if (extension.equals("read"))

 {
    What would be statement here, if I want to skip that file having .read extension ?
 }

Comment: I don't know where you receive the files from and where you save the files to. But i think that you receive the file that all doesn't have .read extension then, you can check it if you already processed it, if like this, then you can do as I mentioned, otherwise you can say your question in more details

Comment: csv files are coming from source and storing into FOLDER. Its a ETL process. So after receiving files to folder etl process those files and after processing convert that file into file.csv.read My concern is if any file come which already has been process and converted to file.csv.read extension, should not be iterated further and converted into file.csv.alreadyprocessed Hope now you got the idea what a trying to say ?

Comment: Now I got your question, I edited the answer you can check it. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void listFile(final String folder, final String ext) {

        ExtFilter filter = new ExtFilter(ext);
        File dir = new File(folder);

        if (dir.isDirectory() == false) {
            System.out.println("Directory does not exists : " + FindFileExtension.FILE_DIR);
            return;
        }

        // list out all the file name and filter by the extension
        String[] list = dir.list(filter);

        if (list.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("no files end with : " + ext);
            return;
        }

        for (String file : list) {
            String temp = new StringBuffer(FindFileExtension.FILE_DIR).append(File.separator).append(file).toString();
            System.out.println("file : " + temp);
            // do your stuff here this file is not processed
        }



    }

    public static class ExtFilter implements FilenameFilter {

        private String ext;

        public ExtFilter(final String ext) {
            this.ext = ext;
        }

        public boolean accept(final File dir, final String name) {
            return (name.endsWith(this.ext));
        }
    }
```

You can do something like that,it might help you